# Sql Update Command - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.Advanced = ISNULL(Item_Pending,0) -
    (ISNULL(Total_items,0) - ISNULL(Items_Pres,0) 
FROM Invent a 
    LEFT JOIN Inventory b ON a.Item_Name = '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'";
```

I am not able to use this update statement without JOIN...
please suggest suitable answer.

Comment: You have not used alias for columns in ISNULL function. Also this does not seem to a proper join at all. It looks like simple where condition. Can you re-check on what you need to do?

Comment: There's something wrong with your parens too.  right at (ISNULL(Total_Items, 0)

Comment: Not to mention, in SQL "DropItemName.SelectedValue" is meaningless and if you're doing that inside of ASP.NET while this particular case isn't vulnerable you're writing code in a manner that is like to attract sql injection attacks.

Comment: i want to update my column Advanced based on simple calculations from other rows in the same table..i put join because its not working without it..but wid Left join its updating all the rows..which i dunt want..a simple update query is needed..i have tried..not wrkn

Answer (score 2):

You just need a simple where clause.  No join.

```
UPDATE 
    Invent
SET 
    Advanced = ISNULL(Item_Pending,0) - ISNULL(Total_items,0) - 
       ISNULL(Items_Pres,0) 
WHERE 
    Item_Name = '<whatever value>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment, I think what you want is this -

```
UPDATE Invent
SET Advanced = ISNULL(Item_Pending,0) -
    ISNULL(Total_items,0) - ISNULL(Items_Pres,0) 
WHERE Item_Name = "'" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'";
```

The `DropItemsName.SelectedValue` seems to be the value you are substituting from your UI code.